# How to use \pretocmd with \verb or \lstinline?

Tags: listings, verbatim, etoolbox

I write my document in other language, then I need to switch to English (switch font) when show code:

```
\newcommand\code[1]{\lstinline{#1}}
\pretocmd{\code}{\begin{otherlanguage}{english}}{}{}
\apptocmd{\code}{\end{otherlanguage}}{}{}
```

Then I face a problem when I try to put a special character into my defined command, like this:

```
\code{HEAD^^}
```

Since I knew this would be fine within those command:

```
\lstinline{HEAD^^} ...or... \lstinline|HEAD^^|
```

So I want to undefined my command and use the original, but this seems not work:

```
\pretocmd{\lstlisting}{\begin{otherlanguage}{english}}{}{}
```

How can I use `\pretocmd` with it?

Comment: `\lstinline` uses several steps in order not to absorb its argument too early and so to be able to print special characters, so defining `\code` with an argument defeats this special handling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I didn't find the answer to my question, but this workaround is just working:

```
\lstset{basicstyle=\selectlanguage{english}\ttfamily}
```

This switch my language (and font) to English everywhere I call `\lstinline` and `\begin{lstlisting} ... \end{lstlisting}`, and switch back to my main language when the scope end. So I no longer need those `\pretocmd` or `\BeforeBeginEnvironment` anymore.